# Scala Design Question - Unify 3 similar endpoints to retrieve from database

Tags: java, scala, generics, design-patterns, finagle

I'm designing a Scala service which has 3 endpoints which are very similar -
a. `getUserByUserID(userIds: List[UserID]): List[User]`
b. `getUserByEmployeeID(employeeIDs: List[EmployeeID]): List[User]`
c. `getUserByDepartmentID(departmentIDs: List[DepartmentID]): List[User]`

Think of User as a case class having many fields but 3 of them for the above endpoints are:

```
case class User(
  userId: UserID,
  employeeID: EmployeeID,
  departmentID: DepartmentID,
)
```

All these IDs are of type `java.util.UUID`.

All 3 endpoints return the `User` object as a list where the appropriate IDs match.

My concern is that there's a lot of repetitive work in this. Only difference is that the `WHERE` clause in the query changes to one of `userID`, `employeeID`, `departmentID`.

I want to minimize this duplication. Is Scala generics a way to do that?

I was thinking of creating a coordinator service that takes in any form of ID and returns the `List[User]` from it

so something like

endpoint1, endpoint2, endpoint3 -> call CoordinatorService --> call Database service

Coordinator service only has 1 method
`def getUserFromAnyID[A <: UUID](id: A): List[User]`

and somehow match the generic `A` to ID to call appropriate database service. At a high level it would look like:

```
def getUserFromAnyID[A <: UUID](id: A): List[User] = {
  // A is a list
  A match {
    case Nil => List.empty()
    case someList =>
     // How to match the type of the object in someList?? It can be any of userId, employeeID, departmentID
     // After matching, it will call the database service:
     <type of list object> match {
        case userID: UserID => databaseService.getUsersByUserID(<pass list of userIds)
        case employeeIds: EmployeeID => databaseService.getUsersByEmployeeIDs(<pass list of employee IDs)
       .
       .
       .
     }  
  }
}
```

Is there an efficient pattern to achieve this?

Comment: I am afraid this might not work because of the type erasure and you would need to use reflection

Comment: Is this a single id or a list of IDs as input parameter? Anyway you can probably achieve what you wrote with a `ClassTag` but you'll need to define 3 types for the 3 IDs and wrap/unwrap them, I don't think you can achieve it with `A` being a subtype of `UUID`.

Comment: You could also just go with an enum (sealed trait or similar) not related to UUID at all and pass it as a second parameter with the list of IDs.

Comment: Yeah the inputs is a list of Ids. So the sealed trait would be an identifier for what type of ID it is? Not sure what the standard pattern is in the industry for these types of endpoints

Comment: Yeah, make an enum ... or pass a `ClassTag`. Either way works. I also don't see what your "coordinator serivice" helps: if you still three endpoints and three database side functions, how is this reducing any repetition. I would just combine the tree DB-functions into one, that takes an enum parameter, and uses it to derive the where clause.